# 404 when trying to create backup in a Google App Engine project

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron, backup

**Setup**

I encountered the 404 problem after following the **unaccepted** answers of the question [AppEngine datastore - backup programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811982/appengine-datastore-backup-programatically)

I have enabled the Datastore Admin, as suggested by one of the answer provider. I can manually trigger a datastore backup in Google App Engine console and the backup runs without any failure.

The code in this question lives in a module called 'app'. Not 'default'.

**The 404 Problem**

This is the cron job in cron.yaml.

```
cron:
- description: Regular backup
  url: /_backup/fullbackup
  schedule: every 24 hours
```

The handler of url will put a backup task in a queue, which in turn make a call to

```
_ah/datastore_admin/backup.create?
gs_bucket_name=%2Fgs%2Ftest.appspot.com%2F21-06-2015&kind=Test&kind=TestContent
&kind=TestDocument&filesystem=gs
```

(I replaced my app id with 'test' here)

This shows a **404** error in the log.

[image]

If I use the above url with my app host name in a brower (i.e. `https://test.appspot.com/_ah/datastore_admin/backup.create?
gs_bucket_name=%2Fgs%2Ftest.appspot.com%2F21-06-2015&kind=Test&kind=TestContent
&kind=TestDocument&filesystem=gs`), I get a 404 too.

[image]

Here is the relevant code in the handler of the route `/_backup/fullbackup`

```
    task = taskqueue.add(
        url='/_ah/datastore_admin/backup.create',
        method='GET',
        target='ah-builtin-python-bundle',
        params={
            'filesystem': 'gs',
            'gs_bucket_name': self.get_bucket_name(),
            'kind': (
                'Test',
                'TestContent',
                'TestDocument'
            )
        }
    )
```

Questions:

- What is the cause of the issue?
- Do I need a queue name in the `taskqueue.add` part of python code?
- In my cron.yaml, do I need to set target to `ah-builtin-python-bundle`?

**EDIT**

The datastore-admin built-in has been enabled, as seen in this screenshot.

And there is no dispatch.yaml

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [AppEngine datastore - backup programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811982/appengine-datastore-backup-programatically)

Comment: @Nick the question has no accepted answer and is **not** about 404 error specifically.

Comment: The lack of an accepted answer is immaterial, really. If you read the question and answers and realize that a working example was posted just 14 days ago. I've just tested this myself and it works. I think the issue may be with the fact that you form your request to test.example.com instead of your-app-id.appspot.com

Comment: @Nick I have clarified my question and added extra info. I used `xxx.appspot.com` host name but still the same 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is related to a queue configuration issue.

A 'default' queue definition was present in the app.yaml prior to the implementation of regular backup. The backup tasks are, as a result, not reaching the  target 'ah-builtin-python-bundle'

If I define a new queue

```
- name: data-backup
  rate: 1/s
  target: ah-builtin-python-bundle
```

Then use this code to insert task,

```
    task = taskqueue.add(
        url='/_ah/datastore_admin/backup.create',
        method='GET',
        queue_name="data-backup",
        params={
            'filesystem': 'gs',
            'gs_bucket_name': self.get_bucket_name(),
            'kind': kinds_list  # A list of ndb model classes I want to backup
        }
    )
```

Then Google app engine can create backup set

Answer (score 6):

Have you [enabled the Datastore Admin](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin#enabling_datastore_admin_for_an_application)? You'll need to have done this to allow the module `ah-builtin-python-bundle` to exist, which is a special module "deployed" to your app when you activate the Datastore admin, which really is responsible for responding to requests to `/_ah/datastore_admin` and spawning MapReduce jobs that read from Datastore and produce the backup files in Cloud Storage (or wherever else you send them to).

Also, another possibility is that you've used `test.appspot.com` hard-coded into your app. Do you own that app id, "test"? From the screenshot of the error you see in the browser, it appears as though you're attempting to back-up to the bucket "`test.appspot.com`", which would be the default bucket for the app with app id "test". However, in the logs screenshot you show, it also attempts to back-up to the "`example.appspot.com`" bucket. Ensure that your app owns these bucket.

Another possibility is that the module which is handling the request isn't `ah-builtin-python-bundle`, but rather another one. This might happen, even if you specify a different target in the task add method, if you have a [dispatch rule](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing#routing_with_a_dispatch_file) which is re-routing the request.