# GAE: Restore ah-builtin-python-bundle and ah-builtin-datastoreservice

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I have accidentally deleted the two versions `ah-builtin-datastoreservice` and `ah-builtin-python-bundle` in one of my GAE projects (written in Go). The implication is that my auto-backups (implemented as described in [Scheduled Backups](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scheduled_backups) and `Google BigQuery Analytics by Jordan Tigani, Siddartha Naidu`) are not working anymore and the datastore admin is not available (response code 404).

It seems that the `ah-builtin-python-bundle` is created when "Enabling the datastore admin" in the [Datastore Admin interface](https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector/datastore/): https://stackoverflow.com/a/31038901/4763102.

Unfortunately, this button is not available anymore - only "Open Datastore Admin" and "Disable writes" buttons are available.

My question is pretty simple: How do I *re-enable* the deleted versions `ah-builtin-datastoreservice` and `ah-builtin-python-bundle` again?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but to handle getting your data into BigQuery and having a copy outside of Cloud Datastore, you are best to use the [Managed Import/Export](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities) service.